# How to create a button (view) which contains a picture and a text using xml Android?

Tags: android, xml, textview, imageview

In my Android app I want to create some buttons (or some views) like that:
[image]

Blue part: image - CONSTANT - not be changed during working session.

Orange part: it is text or other image, depends on value of a variable .

What is the best way to create this view?

Comment: create a custom Component either by extending Button or ImageButton.

Comment: Use framelayout for that, add TextView And Image view as child. and hide/show them as need.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
android:drawableTop="@drawable/my_image"
```

in xml of Button

Comment: And what should I do to control the second part of Button? It may be text or image. Should I use drawableBottom?

Comment: simply use, for xml: android:text="Your Text" and to change text programatically use mButton.setText("Your Text");

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_image.png"
        android:background="@color/Orange"
        android:text="image/text" />
```

Comment: And what should I do if user changes value of variable and the text must be replaced by an image?

Comment: Use this code for dynamic changes                                                 Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.img);
  img.setBounds( 0, 0, 60, 60 );
  button.setCompoundDrawables( null, null, null, img);

Answer (score 0):

just googled it create  custom button in android

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/selectdate"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:onClick="selectFromDate"
            android:src="@drawable/yourimageorxmlfilename" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use one LinearLayout as parent. Implement click listener for
>   this parent
>
> Add 2 ImageViews in this parent

Example :

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:weightSum="2"... >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image1" android:src="@drawable/image_src1" android:layout_weight="1" ... />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image2" android:src="@drawable/image_src2" android:layout_weight="1"... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java code :

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);

parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.setOnClickListener() .../* apply functionality here*/ );
```